# In Swift how do I run a checkpoint on SQLite database

Tags: swift, macos, sqlite, core-data

I have a program that adds data from CSV files to core data. Once I have saved the managed object context to the persistent store I want to run a checkpoint to flush the contents of the WAL file into the SQLite file. I have added code to my class in an attempt to do so but am unable to determine on the line "sqlite3_wal_checkpoint( ...)" what to put in the unsafe pointer  parameter (denoted with ??????? in the code).  Of course if there is a better way, please let me know.

```
class UpdateCoreDataTest: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = true
    var moc: NSManagedObjectContext
    init(moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.moc = moc
        Task {
            await IsDataStoreEmpty(moc: self.moc)
            let fund1 = CSVtoCoreData(fundName: "Fund1", fileName: "Fund1.csv")
            let fund2 = CSVtoCoreData(fundName: "Fund2", fileName: "Fund2.csv")
            let fund3 = CSVtoCoreData(fundName: "Fund3", fileName: "Fund3.csv")
            await fund1.CSVtoCoreDataG(moc: self.moc)
            await fund2.CSVtoCoreDataG(moc: self.moc)
            await fund3.CSVtoCoreDataG(moc: self.moc)
            do {
                try moc.save()
            } catch {
                print("Error saving. \(error)")
            }
//--- start of added code
            let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Chris/Downloads/Persistent Store 2/Funds.sqlite")
            var dataBase: OpaquePointer?
            if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &dataBase) != SQLITE_OK {
                print("Unable to open sqlite file")
            } else {
                print("Succesfully opened sqlite file")
            }
//            sqlite3_wal_checkpoint(dataBase, ??????? )
            sqlite3_close(dataBase)
//--- end of added code
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.isLoading = false
            }
        }
    } // end init
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought more about your statement regarding SQLite automatically running a checkpoint when the last database connection on a database file closes.  So I removed the code between "start of added code" and "end of added code" above.  In its place I put the code below.  Removing the persistent store from the coordinator appears to close the connection between core data and the disk file .  Once this bit of code is executed, a checkpoint is run automatically as you stated. Perfect.

```
let persistentStore = persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.first
do {
     try coreDataContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.remove(persistentStore!)
    } catch {
      print("Unable to remove store -> \(error)")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> The second parameter is the Name of attached database (or NULL). If
> parameter is NULL or points to a zero length string, then the
> specified operation is attempted on all WAL databases attached to
> database connection db.

However, SQLite will automatically checkpoint when the last database connection on a database file closes and WAL file will be deleted. So if you need to open the database to do the checkpoint, then there is probably nothing at all to do.

Comment: I have changed code to sqlite3_wal_checkpoint(dataBase, "") and neither the .sqlite file or the .sqlite-wal file change size i.e. the checkpoint did not occur.  Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder is the problem related to Core Data stores still looking at the file?

Comment: @Chris WAL file will not be deleted after checkpoint, but following writes will reuse it. It will be deleted after last connection closes. If it doesn't, then probably there is some connection still open or not properly closed.

Comment: Makes sense.  Is there a swift command to run that will shut the persistent store off which I would guess should release its connection to the file on the disk.